# Team System: Check-In Changes To Multiple Projects in a Single Changeset?

Tags: tfs

We have a Team System environment where our applications are set-up as separate Team Projects. Often, we run into a scenario where a development task requires updates to code in multiple Team Projects.

In this scenario, what are the pros/cons to having a single changeset that contains coding changes across multiple Team Projects? What are the pros/cons to using a one-changeset-per-Team-Project approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no problem with this approach. Remember that TFS will allow you to rollback to the previous changeset, or inspect the files affected by a changeset (comparing to previous versions) so you can rollback some or all of your changes if required.

Answer (score 2):

Providing the changes are made within a single workspace *and* all the team projects are in the same project collection (this applies to TFS2010) then a single checkin can span multiple team projects.

Within a single server (TFS2005/2008) or team collection (TFS2010) there is a single version control repository with the team projects defining the root folders: all version control operations can span different team projects.