# Get name of "Team project" from changeset object?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-2015

I've written a service that grabs all changesets in all collections on my TFS.

I can dynamically get the collection name of any changeset from the [changeset object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.changeset(v=vs.120).aspx) but I'm having trouble trying to find the **team project name** that the changeset exists in.

Can I somehow find the team project name a changeset belongs to?

```
    foreach (Changeset cs in allChangeSets)
    {
           if (cs.Comment != null && ChangeSetFinderMVC.Utils.TFSUtil.Contains(cs.Comment, id))
           {
                  var cso = new ChangeSetObj();
                  cso.ChangesetId = cs.ChangesetId;
                  cso.CheckinNote = cs.CheckinNote;
                  cso.Comment = cs.Comment;
                  cso.Committer = cs.Committer;
                  cso.CommitterDisplayName = cs.CommitterDisplayName;
                  cso.Collection = cs.VersionControlServer.TeamProjectCollection.Name;
                  cso.TeamProject = "????";

                  changeSetList.Add(cso);

           }
    }
```

Comment: I believe that it's possible to perform a check-in that spans multiple team projects - that may be why you're not finding a direct link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435303/team-system-check-in-changes-to-multiple-projects-in-a-single-changeset

Comment: When the Unbeliever believes the faith is strong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a changeset may apply to multiple projects at once, you will need to look at each item that changed in the changeset and see what project it was associated with.

Inside the `Changeset`, you can access the TFS path of each changed item and see its server path.

```
foreach (Changeset changeSet in changeSets)
{
    foreach (Change change in changeSet.Changes)
    {
        string tfsDir = change.Item.ServerItem;
        // Example: "$/ProjectName/SomeFolders/SomeFile.cs"
        // More logic to handle this string goes here.
    }
}
```

If you need some regex to find the project name, try this: `^\$\/(?<Project>.+?)\/`

Make sure you access the 'Project' group in the regex match.

Answer (score 1):

As @Toomaja said, we can have many TeamProjects related to a single changeset. His solution sugested that you always know what TeamProjects you are looking for. Even you know the TeamProjects beforehand, using a regex to do something that is already done by available methods would low your code lifespan and hold your solution to specific TeamProjects. I would sugest you to get the unique TeamProjects using the server path of the changes using the following:

```
private IEnumerable<string> _GetUniqueTeamProjects(Changeset changeset)
    {
        //We can have many changes in files in differentes TeamProjects within the same changeset
        HashSet<string> teamProjects = new HashSet<string>();

        foreach (var ch in changeset.Changes)
        {
            //Get TeamProject using available repository access and change paths on server side.
            var tp = ch.Item.VersionControlServer.GetTeamProjectForServerPath(ch.Item.ServerItem);
            //Let the HashTable handle the unique value
            teamProjects.Add(tp.Name);
        }

        return teamProjects;
    }
```

Comment: You would probably get more rep for this answer and future answers if you actually explain _what_ is happening in your code, and _why_ it works. StackOverflow is mean't as a Q&A site, and re-usability on answers is important. Explaining your answer may help future readers with similar problems, or it may teach them certain techniques if they can see what is actually going on.

Comment: Thanks for the help!